# In what order should I read Hickman's X-Men?

Tags: marvel, x-men, suggested-order, house-of-x

I've read [House of X/ Powers of X](https://www.marvel.com/comics/discover/1556/house-of-xpowers-of-x), and [Dawn of X Vol. 1](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/79986/dawn_of_x_vol_1_trade_paperback). I've just bought Vol. 2. I've noticed that there are other series, such as X of Swords and Reign of X. I've looked at a few lists, but have been unable to find a consensus. Should I just continue with Dawn of X, or would it be better to instead read each line (Marauders, Excalibur, etc.) separately? I prefer to read collected volumes, rather than single issues, whenever possible.

Comment: https://www.comicbookherald.com/the-complete-marvel-reading-order-guide/jonathan-hickman-x-men-reading-order/

Comment: https://marvelguides.com/dawn-of-x-reading-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Comic Book Herald](https://www.comicbookherald.com/the-complete-marvel-reading-order-guide/jonathan-hickman-x-men-reading-order/) had this to say:

> it’s really down to personal preference, and I’d advise sticking with
> the books that do it for you. For the completists like myself, though,
> those Dawn of X collections may seem awfully tempting.

The Dawn of X books present the story chronologically, with 1 issue from each of the 6 series (X-Men, Marauders, Excalibur, New Mutants, X-Force, and Fallen Angels). I'm not sure how important each individual series is, to the overall story. My impression so far is that X-Force is the most important because:

> this is the series where Xavier is assassinated.

Hickman's X-men run concludes in the [X of Swords](https://www.marvel.com/comics/discover/1994/x-of-swords) crossover event. The X-Men comics are relaunched in [Reign of X](https://www.marvel.com/comics/discover/2059/reign-of-x), starting with [Hellfire Gala](https://www.marvel.com/comics/discover/2188/hellfire-gala).